# How do retrieve a file from Google Drive in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I just want to download a particular file which is on my google drive and download it on by android device through button click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please search on SO before ask any question

Comment: i haven't found  the answer yet.. if you do please share with me.. i would like to see it